# How to change the BG color of a ROW based on today's date

Tags: excel

Two part question. I have a COL, the F col, which I insert dates in the format of `02/16/13`. In the K COL I want to automatically insert `03/16/13` in the same row (30 days ahead).

At the top of the spreadsheet, I insert TODAY date on open. If TODAY date is equal to or after the date in COL K, I want that entire ROW bg color to change.

I tired conditional formatting, but I am unsure of the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the date formatting, you could do something like `=(Today()>=K1)` and then set the formatting rules and copy/paste formatting down the entire column K.

For the date insertion in column K, in K1 put the formula: `=F1+30` then drag that formula down the entire column K.

You could also do the date insertion in column K with a macro in the Worksheet code module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(byVal Target as Range)
If Not Intersect(Target,Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Offset(0,5).Value = DateAdd("d", 30, Target.Value)
End If
End Sub
```